# Asterisk. Сокращение строк изпользуя переменные

Tags: asterisk, extension

в файле extentions.conf есть много одинаковых контекстов с содержимым  такого вида:

```
[КонтекстУникНомера]
exten => _[78]XXXXXXXXXX,1,Answer()
exten => _[78]XXXXXXXXXX,n,Set(CALLERID(number)=УникальныйНомер)
exten => _[78]XXXXXXXXXX,n,Set(OutNum=${EXTEN})
exten => _[78]XXXXXXXXXX,n,Goto(context0,s,1)
```

Как можно уменьшить количество строчек? Как быть с уникальными номерами?

Comment: Используйте макросы, а уникальный номер передавайте через параметры при вызове макроса

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понятна суть вопроса, но вроде как с версии 1.4 можно писать так:

```
[КонтекстУникНомера]
exten => _[78]XXXXXXXXXX,1,Answer()
 same => n,Set(CALLERID(number)=УникальныйНомер)
 same => n,Set(OutNum=${EXTEN})
 same => n,Goto(context0,s,1)
```